# Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressConverter::convertMany() must be of the type array, null given,

Tags: magento2

I have created a pop up html form for sending mail to admin panel, it can pop up and keys in data but somehow it showed error while submitting.

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Block/Popup.php

```
<?php

namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Popup extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [], \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry)
{
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}

public function getCurrentCategory() {
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}

public function getCurrentProduct() {
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}


/**
 * @return string
 */
  public function getFormAction()
  {

    return $this->getUrl('productenquiry/index/send', ['_secure' => true]);
  }
}
```

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Controller/Index/Send.php

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail;

class Send extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

/**
 * Recipient email config path
 */
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'email_section/sendmail/email_section_sendmail_email_template';
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
 */
protected $inlineTranslation;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $_escaper;
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

/**
 * Post user question
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (!$post) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

    try {
        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);

        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name']),
            'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),
        ];

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('email_section_sendmail_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->getTransport();


        $transport->sendMessage(); ;
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
        );

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
        );

    }

    return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
}

}
```

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/email/email_file.html

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

 <table class="message-details">
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Name"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Email"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Product Name"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.product_name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><b>{{trans "Message"}}</b></p>
<p>{{var data.message}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml

```
<?php
 $myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Popup');


?>



<div class="content" style="display:none" id="popup_content">
<form
    class="form enquire"
    id="enquire-form"
    action="<?= $myBlock->escapeUrl($myBlock->getFormAction()) ?>"
    method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <Label for="#name">Name</Label>
        <input name="name" id="name" title="Name" class="form-control input-text" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <Label for="#email">Email</Label>
        <input id="email" name="email" title="Email" class="form-control input-text" type="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <Label for="#message">Message</Label>
        <input id="message" name="message" title="Message" type="text" class="form-control input-text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <Label for="#product_name">Product Name</Label>
        <input id="product_name" name="product_name" title="Product Name" type="text" value="<?php if ($currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct()) { echo $currentProduct->getName();}; ?>" class="form-control input-text" readonly><br>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>


<div id="click-section" class="click-section">
<br>
<button type="button" class="action primary" id="click_section2">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Click Me'"></span>
</button>
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function($,modal) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            title: 'Popup',
            buttons: []
        };

        $( "#click_section2" ).click(function() {
            modal(options, $('#popup_content'));
            $('#popup_content').modal('openModal');
        });
    }
);
```

When I click submit button:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressConverter::convertMany() must be of the type array, null given,
```

Comment: You need to pass array in app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Controller/Index/Send.php addTo method like addto(['email' => 'test@gmail.com', 'name' => 'TEST']) OR addto('test@gmail.com', 'TEST')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this **$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope)** you should get either string or array value, I think you are getting this as **null** value.

**Complete Explanation as shown below**

You have call the **addTo** method as given in example which accepts
**@param array|string $address**

Explanation :-

```
/**
     * Add to address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function addTo($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('to', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }
```

**addTo** method calls **addAddressByType** method that accepts again array or string by passing your data as argument on second position as $email **(@param string|array $email)**.

Example :-

```
/**
     * Handles possible incoming types of email (string or array)
     *
     * @param string $addressType
     * @param string|array $email
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    private function addAddressByType(string $addressType, $email, ?string $name = null): void
    {
        if (is_string($email)) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
            return;
        }
        $convertedAddressArray = $this->addressConverter->convertMany($email);
        if (isset($this->messageData[$addressType])) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType] = array_merge(
                $this->messageData[$addressType],
                $convertedAddressArray
            );
        } else {
            $this->messageData[$addressType] = $convertedAddressArray;
        }
    }
```

And as you value passes is null and not a string it does not go to below code section of method

```
if (is_string($email)) {
     $this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
     return;
}
```

and goes for further execution which requires array to be passed in **convertMany** function.

**Or your config path might be wrong Please refer below image instruction to correct your path if it is wrong**

[image]

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

Comment: Hi. thank you for your answer, sorry that I am new and may I know which part should be changed in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check what value you are getting when you print this $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope)


Have you set the default configuration value for this setting?

Or have you set any value from admin?

Comment: @hill2011 May be your path can be incorrect, I have updated my answer with instruction about how to define correct config path.